# Identifying my flowerhorn fish type

Tags: fish, identification

We recently got a Flowerhorn fish and we love the experience of it. But now our curiosity hitting what type of flowerhorn fish we have. We got it from his previous owner who is not a breeder and didn't know the exact type. Google-Fu made us confused if he is Red Dragon Flowerhorn or Super Red Dragon Flowerhorn or maybe Kamfa Flowerhorn. Bellow is the picture:

[image]